# Use bcrypt to store password takes no effect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use mongodb to store my user table, and use bcrypt to store password. However , the stored password is all in real text. My node js code is below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type:String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
meta: {
    createAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    updateAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
      }
  }
})
UserSchema.pre('save',function(next){
var user = this
if(this.isNew){
    this.meta.createAt = this.meta.updateAt = Date.now()
}
else{
    this.meta.updateAt = Date.now()
}

bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR,function(err, salt){
    if(err) return next(err)
        console.log('salt'+salt)
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            console.log('hash'+hash)
            if(err) 
                return next(err)

            console.log('set user password' + hash)
            user.password = hash
            next()

        })
})

next()
})
```

after that , i use db.users.find() in my mongo terminal , all I see is the password stored in real text:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("54d2f5a4162a7335c0036cae"), "name" : "12", "password" : "12", "meta" : { "updateAt" : ISODate("2015-02-05T04:46:28.246Z"), "createAt" : ISODate("2015-02-05T04:46:28.246Z") }, "__v" : 0 }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("54d2f89c0675b329c3e783d4"), "name" : "34", "password" : "34", "meta" : { "updateAt" : ISODate("2015-02-05T04:59:08.285Z"), "createAt" : ISODate("2015-02-05T04:59:08.285Z") }, "__v" : 0 }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("54d2f9703b55cdf5c32af5b2"), "name" : "457", "password" : "457", "meta" : { "updateAt" : ISODate("2015-02-05T05:03:23.338Z"), "createAt" : ISODate("2015-02-05T05:03:23.338Z") }, "__v" : 0 }

and because of that , my compare function always return false:

```
UserSchema.methods = {
comparePassword: function(_password, cb){
    bcrypt.compare(_password, this.password, function(err, isMatched){
        if(err) 
            return cb(err)

        cb(null, isMatched)
    })
}
}
```

Could somebody help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that because you have an extra `next()` immediately after your call to `bcrypt.genSalt()`, the value of `user.password` hasn't changed before the entry is saved to the database. So remove the `next()` immediately after `bcrypt.genSalt()` and it should work as expected.